# How can I reverse the positions of two (unequal width) columns so that the wider one is always against the inner margin?

Tags: two-column, multicol, double-sided, parcolumns

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to use it to write a spotlessly-typesetted draft of my novel (from the rough, typewritten hard draft) for MFA program applications, and eventually to send to publishers. I realize that with respect to the latter, many strongly prefer MS Word, but Word simply *can't* do the things I need done.

So. Here's my current problem (plus a couple other questions about related issues). Sorry in advance for the long post--please bear with me!

Half of my chapters (the odd-numbered ones) use a layout in which any given page has two columns of varying length, as well as outer margin notes. I need the wider of the two columns to always be flush with the inner margin such that, for any double-page spread, the wider columns will be next to each other on opposite pages, with the narrower columns on opposite sides of the central pair of wider columns. Basically, the text for the wider columns is its own separate thing, and the text for the narrower columns is commentary. (This of course means they need to remain separated from each other while having their respective texts flow continuously across page breaks--which won't be a problem, given that they're columns and not boxes, right?).

The **\parcolumns** package seems like a good choice as far as the differing width issue, but I can't seem to find any information about how to use it to form this layout that I need. (In other words, it seems that, from what I've been able to find, the first column in **\parcolumns** will always be on the same side). Would it be possible to write some set of conditionals directly into the code of parcolumns itself so that the package would do this automatically? Or could one just put all that in the preamble of the document?

(Amidst a lot of research while *not* writing this, I noticed on p. 16 of the [article/guide for the **\multicol** environment](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf), they coded `\moveright\multicol@leftmargin` as the first in a series of operations to go about switching the order of the columns for R->L languages. Could this maybe play a role?)

[REMOVED as irrelevant; see UPDATE]

Finally: a vital caveat I should mention here is that I need to be able to put some sort of smaller text boxes within the narrower of the two columns that are, say, `0.6\linewidth` of the narrower column, are flush with the inner margin of the column, then have the body of the column's text wrap around them. Also, because I've developed my own alternate format for basic prose writing which uses non-indented text blocks of varying widths to distinguish between the text of the narration (full line width) versus that of dialogue (REMOVED due to improvement; see UPDATE) I need to be able to use these commands in the wide column in question here...which, as I've learned from lots of reading, just wouldn't work using longtables. Thus, these chapters absolutely **must** be assembled using actual columns.

**UPDATE:**

Upon further reading (both of posts on this site, as well as careful inspection of the Implementation section of [the user guide for **\parcolumns**)](ftp://ftp.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sauerj/parcolumns.pdf), I've discovered the **\ifoddpage** package. So, to add a bit more specificity here, might it work to make the following modifications to **parcolumns.sty**?

a) Add `\RequirePackage{ifoddpage}` to the preamble.

b) Between lines 95 and 96, set `\checkoddpage \@ifoddpage{`(lines 96-173, with the "<" in `\loop\ifnum\count@<\pc@columncount%` of lines 96, 111, 125, 144, and 164 changed to "=")`}{`(original lines 96-173)`}`, or some equivalent conditional.

I'm sure there must be some much more sophisticated, less code-clunky way of doing this, but I'm not sure how...Also, should there be any other section of the code set under the conditional? Is **\ifoddpage** even capable of handling conditionals of this size? And is there something important I'm missing about a command like `\checkoddpage`, like I would have to write some extra code for the package to be able to even detect page numbers?

I've gotten everything else more or less figured out, from the minipage/wrapfigure boxes in my first columns to the margin notes, to a better set of commands that will allow text to flow continuously across pages for my alternate prose format more generally (using the **adjustwidth** environment from **\changepage**, instead of using **\parbox**...I'm almost there. I just need these columns to flip. Any non-**\parcolumns** alternatives to suggest?

**UPDATE #2**

Per Stephan Lehmke's request/suggestion, here is the code and images of the PDF produced.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpage,twosides]{bookest}
%
\geometry{textheight=9in,vmarginratio=1:1,outermargin=1.5in,innermargin=.5in,%
marginparwidth=1.25in,marginparsep=.2in}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% 
% % % % % [Many lines of new commands have been omitted, as they are not relevant here.]
%
%%%%% For use in \parcolumns environment
\newcommand{\warfo}{\begin{wrapfigure}{o}[.15in]{1.5in} \begin{minipage}[t]{1.4in} %
\noindent \Large}
\newcommand{\warfi}{\begin{wrapfigure}{i}[.15in]{1.5in} \begin{minipage}[t]{1.4in} %
\noindent \Large}
\newcommand{\wraf}{\end{minipage} \vspace{-.265in} \end{wrapfigure}}
\newcommand{\stm}{\marginnote}
%
\begin{document}
%
\chapter{Sample Experimental Chapter Layout}
%
\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy=true,sloppyspaces=true,nofirstindent=true,colwidths={1=2.8in, %
2=3.5in}]{2}
%
\colchunk[1]{\small \indent \lipsum[14] \warfi{Sample  wrapped text box, using a minipage %
inside a wrapfig environment.} \wraf \lipsum[15] \warfo{Another sample wrapped text box, % 
placed along the inner side of the \\ column.} \wraf \lipsum[16]  \lipsum[17]}
%
\colchunk[2]{\Large \indent \stm{\normalsize \textbf{Sample margin note, always to be on % 
the outer margin. \\ ---------- \\ Aside from the placement of the margin note, the layout %
 of this odd page is incorrect. The order of the two columns should be switched, so that % 
 the larger/wider column is placed along the inner margin, and the smaller/thinner column % 
 is placed along the outer margin.}} \lipsum[10] \lipsum[11] \lipsum[12] \lipsum[13] %
 \stm{\textbf{\normalsize The layout of this even page is correct, with the larger column % 
 on the inner margin and the smaller column on the outer one, with the wrapped text box on %
 the inner edge of the smaller column. \\ ---------- \\ However, can I suppress this extra%
 line between paragraphs in the inner column?}} \lipsum[14]}
%
\end{parcolumns}
%
\end{document}
```

Here are the pages produced. Everything is explained in the margin notes.
[image]
[image]

Note the blank line between larger, inner paragraphs on p.2--How can I get rid of that breaking when entering a `\marginnote`?

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting page layout to create, but I'm afraid the explanation is too long to be fully understood without some illustration. Could you typeset some example text with the tools you already found (posting that source here), make a screenshot of the result and draw on that some arrows (with a drawing program) illustrating what is not in the right place and where it should go?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Stephan. I will update the post and post a link to the .jpeg files for the pages generated. Everything is explained in the margin notes on the pages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT** (July 25, 2012)

There is a small bug concerning the column separating space in the version below.  I fixed that and wrapped up the whole `parcolumns` patch in a tiny package named `parcolsx`, so that you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{parcolsx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter heading}
\begin{parcolumns}[%
  sloppy        = true,
  sloppyspaces  = true,
  nofirstindent = true,
  colwidths     = {1=0.43\textwidth, 2=0.53\textwidth}
]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\small\indent%
  \lipsum[14] 
  \lipsum[15]
  \lipsum[16]
  \lipsum[17]
}
\colchunk[2]{\Large\indent%
  \lipsum[10]
  \lipsum[11]
  \lipsum[12]
  \lipsum[13]
}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Note the additional key/value pair `alternate = true` in the arguments of the `parcolumns` environment.  This way the alternating columns can be activated at will.

The package `parcolsx` to be saved in a file named `parcolsx.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{parcolsx}

\RequirePackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

% add the additional boolean key `alternate' 
% to the `parcolumns' environment
\newif\ifpc@alternate
\define@key{parcolumns}{alternate}[true]{%
\pc@boolkey{pc@alternate}{#1}%
}

% slightly modify the `\pc@placeboxes' macro to distinguish between odd
% and even pages, if the option `alternate=true' was passed to the
% `parcolumns' environment
\def\pc@placeboxes{%
  \global\let\@tempa\relax%
  \hb@xt@\linewidth{%
    \vfuzz30ex %
    \vbadness\@M%
    \splittopskip\z@skip%
    % odd is the default
    \ifpc@alternate \checkoddpage \else \oddpagetrue \fi%
    \ifoddpage
      % count up from 1 to N_col
      \count@\z@%
      \loop\ifnum\count@<\pc@columncount%
        \advance\count@\@ne%
        \pcx@placeboxes@body%
        \ifnum\count@<\pc@columncount%
          \strut\hfill\ifpc@rulebetween\vrule\hfill\fi%
        \fi%
      \repeat%
    \else
      % count down from N_col to 1
      \count@\pc@columncount%
      \loop\ifnum\count@>\z@%
        \pcx@placeboxes@body%
        \advance\count@\m@ne%
        \ifnum\count@>\z@%
          \strut\hfill\ifpc@rulebetween\vrule\hfill\fi%
        \fi%
      \repeat%
    \fi
  }%
  \@tempa%
}

% the fraction of `\pc@placeboxes' that does not depend on the page
% parity
\def\pcx@placeboxes@body{%
  \expandafter\ifvoid\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname%
    \hskip\csname pc@column@width@\number\count@\endcsname%
  \else%
    \expandafter\setbox\expandafter\@tempboxa%
      \expandafter\vsplit\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname%
        to \dp\strutbox%
    \expandafter\@tempdimb\csname pc@column@width@\number\count@\endcsname%
    \hbox to \@tempdimb {\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa}\hfill}%
  \fi%
  \expandafter\ifvoid\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname%
  \else%
    \global\let\@tempa\pc@placeboxes%
  \fi%
}
```

On a side note: that patch also fixes the incompatibility of the `parcolumns` with the `wrapfigure` package.  I will comment on this in the other thread: [Wrapfigure-Minipage Woes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64157)

---

**Original answer** (including column separator bug)

You ask for many different things and your sample document contains a lot of stuff that might not be helpful here.  However, I might have found a solution for your column switching problem.

Please see this more minimalistic example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\def\pc@placeboxes{%
  \global\let\@tempa\relax%
  \hb@xt@\linewidth{%
    \vfuzz30ex %
    \vbadness\@M%
    \splittopskip\z@skip%
    \checkoddpage\ifoddpage
      \count@\z@%
      \loop\ifnum\count@<\pc@columncount%
        \advance\count@\@ne%
        \my@placeboxes@body%
      \repeat%
    \else
      \count@\pc@columncount%
      \loop\ifnum\count@>\z@%
        \my@placeboxes@body%
        \advance\count@\m@ne%
      \repeat%
    \fi
  }%
  \@tempa%
}

\def\my@placeboxes@body{%
  \expandafter\ifvoid\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname%
    \hskip\csname pc@column@width@\number\count@\endcsname%
  \else%
    \expandafter\setbox\expandafter\@tempboxa%
      \expandafter\vsplit\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname%
        to \dp\strutbox%
    \vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa}%
  \fi%
  \expandafter\ifvoid\csname pc@column@\number\count@\endcsname%
  \else%
    \global\let\@tempa\pc@placeboxes%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\count@>\z@%
    \strut%
    \hfill%
    \ifpc@rulebetween%
      \vrule%
      \hfill%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter heading}

\begin{parcolumns}[%
  sloppy        = true,
  sloppyspaces  = true,
  nofirstindent = true,
  colwidths     = {1=0.43\textwidth, 2=0.53\textwidth}
]{2}

\colchunk[1]{\small\indent%
  \lipsum[14] 
  \lipsum[15]
  \lipsum[16]
  \lipsum[17]
}

\colchunk[2]{\Large\indent%
  \lipsum[10]
  \lipsum[11]
  \lipsum[12]
  \lipsum[13]
}

\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

I slightly modified the macro `\pc@placeboxes` from the parcolumns package, so that it distinguishes between odd and even pages.  The actual check is done using macros from the `changepage` package, which is why it is loaded in the preamble.  You will have to compile at least twice, since this relies on page lables.

The resulting output is, I think, what you desire, i.e. the columns interchange at every page break:

[image]
[image]

I have not bothered about the margin notes and you might experience side effects.  If that is the case you should better open a new question and tackle one problem at a time.

**EDIT** (July 22, 2012)

The parcolumns package works in two steps: first, the contents of each
column is typeset in a box. This is done by the `\colchunk` command.
Second, for every line on the output page one line from each column box
is extracted and placed on the page.  That is done by the
`\pc@placeboxes` macro.

So, assuming `N` columns, the original `\pc@placeboxes` in principle
does the following: For colums `i=1` up to `i=N` the first line of the
`i`-th column box is cut and pasted on the page.  If `i<N` a column
separating space is inserted.

I simply hooked into this macro and inverted the order on every second
page: the modified `\pc@placeboxes` does exactly the same as the
original one for odd pages.  However, for even pages it loops from `i=N`
down to `i=1` when cutting and pasting the lines from the column boxes.

The problem with the `wrapfig` stuff very likely stems from this
two-step approach.  Having not looked into the `wrapfig` package I can
just guess that it uses `\parshape` to modify the shape of the typeset
paragraph.  This will influence what is typeset into the column boxes.
Apparently, things go wrong when the lines of the column boxes are
distributed on the page.  I can not, unfortunately, offer a solution for
this issue at the moment (actually I hoped that some of the TeX gurus
here would have a suggestion for you).

Comment: Terrific, yes, the output is, in essence, exactly what I've been looking for. I added your solution to the preamble of my "UPDATE #2" code, and it's not the margin notes that cause problems, but rather, the wrapfig/minipage boxes. They get thrown all over the place when I compile, and also cause strange empty wrapfigure spaces in the inner column (which should have nothing to do with them at all). But hey, you're right, this is why we open new questions. I'll be working on that directly. All that aside, this is **tremendously** helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Isaac Sorry about the wrapfigure problem.  I have never used these, but I am sure that there are plenty of experts in this forum here.  Please try to keep the follow-up question as short as possible and add a minimal working example that only uses what is needed to reproduce the problem.  This will tremendously increase your chances to get a useful answer.

Comment: Don't be sorry! This is an excellent solution to my _basic_ problem. I've been experimenting with it and it works perfectly when I don't use the wrapfigure-minipage environments. I didn't originally ask for help with correctly typesetting of those because I didn't realize at the time that there would be "side effects," so no worries. Anyway, thanks for the advice on the follow-up question. I'll let the code and the images speak for themselves, mostly.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your `/pc@placeboxes` modification in a bit more detail as to the processes involved? I'm still far too new at this to be able to understand what's going on exactly, just by reading over all the code on my own. I would very much appreciate it. (Also, it would certainly be helpful for the follow-up question.) Thanks again!

Comment: @Isaac - please see the edits in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is (and will continue to be) very helpful! I'm updating the follow-up question with my discovery that the wrapfigure problem on even pages disappears if I use the `{i}`  placement specifier for `\wrapfigure` (instead of `{o}`), and I will add to it that you've updated your answer as well.

Comment: @Isaac, I just discovered a small bug in my code when attempting to answer your follow-up question.  It turned out that the `wrapfigure` problem had nothing to do with my modifications, but is an incompatibility of `wrapfigure` and `parcolumns`.  However, the code above should also resolve this issue.  I will shortly comment that in your other thread.

Comment: alexurba, I was using this solution for a while and it has suddenly stopped working... not sure if it is because of an update to parcolumns or what.

Comment: @alexurba What theobear is speaking about: [parcolsx broken after update to paracolumns?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158624) And: Did you already know `pdfcolparcolumns` from `oberdiek` bundle?

Comment: @theobear - sorry for the late response.  Except for answering this question, I have never used `parcolumns` myself.  So I forgot everything about it by now.  Currently, I have no time to dive into it again, but I can have a look at the problem end of next week.

Comment: @Speravir - I was not aware of `pdfcolparcolumns`.  Do you think it this package could help to solve @theobear's problem?

Comment: @alexurba: It did not change anything in the ouput if his (?) minimal example. but there are a bunch of additions and fixes, see the documentation.

Comment: @alexurba, Thanks so much for your response. I appreciate you taking the time. If you figure out the problem please put your answer [here as well](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158624/parcolsx-broken-after-update-to-paracolumns) so I can award you the bounty (if you care for such things. :)

Comment: @alexurba, just checking in to see if you had a chance to look at this. Thanks!

Comment: @theobar - sorry, I have not forgotten about this, but there was simply no time yet.  I am surprised that nobody else here helped you so far.

Comment: @alexurba, Hello, It looks like the project that uses this package may get some funding... if it goes though I wonder If I could hire a couple of consulting hours to get this issue ironed out. You can contact me via my website which is listed on my bio page. THANKS

Comment: Not sure what to say, @theobear.  It is the lag of time, not money, that keeps me from working on this.  I could issue another bounty for the problem, but last time that did not help either.  (Is there no way to exchange private messages on stackexchange other than via your website?)

Comment: @alexurba, no problem, I understand completely I just wanted you to know I appreciate your help and think that your time is valuable. I'll see if I can edit the question so it might be clearer what I am trying to do and then issue a bounty.